# How come function is first declared before a variabe but then the same function can't be resolved but the variable can?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

The reason why in `(A)` "function" is printed out is probably because of hoisting respectively because in the creation stage the function is created in the variable object before the variable `foo`.

But if the function is created before the variable `foo`, how come I can't resolve the function (see `(D)`) but instead I can resolve the variable (see `(C)`)?

```
(function() {

 console.log(typeof foo); // (A) function pointer

var foo = 'hi';

function foo() {
 return 'hello';
 }

  console.log(foo); // (C) hi
  foo();// (D) TypeError: foo is not a function
})();
```

Comment: You can always *resolve* the variable `foo`. But at the time you try to call it's value, it holds a string (as evidenced by the log in the line before).

Answer (score 1):

The is the order of events

1. `var foo` is hoisted and declares the variable `foo`.
2. `function foo() {}` is hoisted, redeclares the variable `foo` and assigns it a value (a function)
3. `console.log(typeof foo)` logs the function
4. `foo = 'hi'` assigns a string to `foo`, overwriting the previous value (the function)
5. `console.log(foo)` logs the string
6. `foo()` throws an error because a string is not a function

Answer (score 0):

functions declaration are run before everything else

```
(function() {

function foo() { //Function declaration
  return 'hello';
}

console.log(typeof foo); // (A) function pointer
console.log(typeof bar); // (B) undefined

var foo = 'hi',
 bar = function() { //Function expression
   return 'world';
 };

console.log(foo); // (C) hi
  foo();// (D) error
})();
```

Imagine your program looks like this, because foo() is the first thing to run

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you variable foo is hoisted but without initialisation, so it's undefined. Then it's overwritten by the function declaration. That's why typeof returns Function. Then the value is assigned to it ('hi'), so trying to call the function fails.

In the case of bar, you are using the Function expression syntax (`var bar = function()`) rather than Function decalration (`function bar()`), so bar is hoisted as an undefined variable and later a value is assigned to it.